# Efficiently removing lower half-byte in a byte array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have a long byte array and I want to remove the lower nibble (the lower 4 bits) of every byte and move the rest together such that the result occupies half the space as the input.

For example, if my input is `057ABC23`, my output should be `07B2`.

My current approach looks like this:

```C++
// in is unsigned char*
size_t outIdx = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < input_length; i += 8) 
{
    in[outIdx++] = (in[i    ] & 0xF0) | (in[i + 1] >> 4);
    in[outIdx++] = (in[i + 2] & 0xF0) | (in[i + 3] >> 4);
    in[outIdx++] = (in[i + 4] & 0xF0) | (in[i + 5] >> 4);
    in[outIdx++] = (in[i + 6] & 0xF0) | (in[i + 7] >> 4);
}
```

... where I basically process 8 bytes of input in every loop, to illustrate that I can assume `input_length` to be divisible by 8 (even though it's probably not faster than processing only 2 bytes per loop). The operation is done in-place, overwriting the input array.

Is there a faster way to do this? For example, since I can read in 8 bytes at a time anyway, the operation could be done on 4-byte or 8-byte integers instead of individual bytes, but I cannot think of a way to do that. The compiler doesn't come up with something itself either, as I can see the output code still operates on bytes (-O3 seems to do some loop unrolling, but that's it).

I don't have control over the input, so I cannot store it differently to begin with.

Comment: Is it supposed to be portable or can you use architecture-specific intrinsics?

Comment: The requirements are that it needs to run on a Windows x86_64 machine.

Comment: I was thinking about sth similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134763/combine-packed-nibbles-into-packed-bytes

Comment: x86_64 has 128-bit registers. You can adapt a generic 64-bit algorithm to 128 bits using [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2).

Comment: The referenced question looks similar (it has one nibble per 16 bit instead of one per 8bit, and it's the "lowest" one instead of the "highest" one of its section, but otherwise the idea looks to be the same), however, I cannot understand what all of that code does. Could you explain what it does, or how to transform it to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is a general technique for bit-fiddling to swap bits around. Suppose you have a 64-bit number, containing the following nibbles:

```
HxGxFxExDxCxBxAx
```

Here by `x` I denote a nibble whose value is unimportant (you want to delete it). The result of your bit-operation should be a 32-bit number `HGFEDCBA`.

First, delete all the `x` nibbles:

```
HxGxFxExDxCxBxAx & *_*_*_*_*_*_*_*_ = H_G_F_E_D_C_B_A_
```

Here I denote 0 by `_`, and binary `1111` by `*` for clarity.

Now, replicate your data:

```
H_G_F_E_D_C_B_A_ << 4 = _G_F_E_D_C_B_A__
H_G_F_E_D_C_B_A_ | _G_F_E_D_C_B_A__ = HGGFFEEDDCCBBAA_
```

Notice how some of your target nibbles are together. You need to retain these places, and delete duplicate data.

```
HGGFFEEDDCCBBAA_ & **__**__**__**__ = HG__FE__DC__BA__
```

From here, you can extract the result bytes directly, or do another iteration or two of the technique.

Next iteration:

```
HG__FE__DC__BA__ << 8 = __FE__DC__BA____
HG__FE__DC__BA__ | __FE__DC__BA____ = HGFEFEDCDCBABA__
HGFEFEDCDCBABA__ & ****____****____ = HGFE____DCBA____
```

Last iteration:

```
HGFE____DCBA____ << 16 = ____DCBA________
HGFE____DCBA____ | ____DCBA________ = HGFEDCBADCBA____
HGFEDCBADCBA____ >> 32 = ________HGFEDCBA
```

Comment: Hmm, essentially, this would still process the whole thing byte by byte, though. I don't see why this would be faster than directly doing it byte by byte as in my current code.

Comment: CPU processes 64-bit data elements (registers) as fast as it can, not byte by byte. For example, the first logical operation (`AND`) will process one 64-bit register, which contains 8 useful 4-bit data elements.

Comment: That's true, but you would still have 4 iterations to arrive at the result, right? Wouldn't that result in more or less the same number of operations as the code operating on the single bytes?

Comment: No. That's my guess. I suggest you try it and see. For me, just interesting whether it's a good algorithm. For you, maybe solves the problem.

Comment: You might be able to improve it further by using 128-bit arithmetic (SSE). Or 256-bit (AVX2). I have little experience with it, so cannot post an answer, just a general idea. These instruction sets have powerful instructions for swapping stuff at byte and word level (shuffle/permute). That's what they are doing in the linked question, though I don't understand it in details.

Comment: Ok, I quickly benchmarked it and it came around 2ms for your approach instead of 4ms with my original approach (with around 8MB of data on my machine). Thanks! :)
(deleted previous comment that said 3.2ms, that was an error)

Comment: Yes, I unfortunately also don't understand the referenced question. I get the general idea, but not enough to be comfortable putting this in production code. But saving these 2ms on something that's executed very often is already worth a lot!

Comment: We actually missed a small but important detail. The system is of course little endian, which means that the proposed solution as-is would flip the nibbles in the result.

That means that instead of the first iteration being "value |= value << 4", it should be "value = (value >> 4) | (value << 8)". It's one more operation, but still almost twice as fast.

Comment: using AVX-512 would be even faster than AVX2

Comment: If you could post an answer using either, that'd be very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

All x64-86 (and most x86) cpus have SSE2.

For each 16-bit lane do
`t = (x & 0x00F0) | (x >> 12)`.
Then use the pack instruction to truncate each 16-bit lane to 8-bits.
For example, `0xABCD1234` would become `0x00CA0031` then the pack would make it `0xCA31`.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

void squish_32bytesTo16 (unsigned char* src, unsigned char* dst) {
    const __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi16(0x00F0);
    __m128i src0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(void*)src);
    __m128i src1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(void*)(src + sizeof(__m128i)));
    __m128i t0 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_and_si128(src0, mask), _mm_srli_epi16(src0, 12));
    __m128i t1 = _mm_or_si128(_mm_and_si128(src1, mask), _mm_srli_epi16(src1, 12));
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(void*)dst, _mm_packus_epi16(t0, t1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put the resulting code here for future reference, it now looks like this (assuming the system is little endian, and the input length is a multiple of 8 bytes):

```c++
void compress(unsigned char* in, size_t input_length)
{
    unsigned int* inUInt = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(in);
    unsigned long long* inULong = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(in);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < input_length / 8; ++i) 
    {
        unsigned long long value = inULong[i] & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0;
        value = (value >> 4) | (value << 8);
        value &= 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00;
        value |= (value << 8);
        value &= 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000;
        value |= (value << 16);
        inUInt[i] = static_cast<unsigned int>(value >> 32);
    }
}
```

Benchmarked very roughly it's around twice as fast as the code in the question (using MSVC19 /O2).

Note that this is basically the solution anatolyg posted before (just put into code), so upvote that answer instead if you found this helpful.